# Flink run failing to submit jar

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile, continuous-integration, apache-flink

Trying to submit WordCount jar to flink  hosted on EKS cluster.

On docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
flink run -m jobmanager:8081 -p20 /opt/flink/examples/batch/WordCount.jar
# # Prevent the script from immediately exiting
trap "echo 'Script is running...'; wait" SIGINT SIGTERM

# # Wait for the Flink job to complete
wait
```

without entrypoint.sh if i deploy the flink can login to the pod or use port-forward and can submit the jar, BUT when I enable the ENTRYPOINT on dockerfile could not access the localhost:8081 as well and job submission will through the below error.

kubectl logs <podname>

```
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '20ad9418' at 'null' in 'null'
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '34e9fd99' at 'null' in 'null'
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '3c41ed1d' at 'null' in 'null'
Executing WordCount example with default input data set.
Use --input to specify file input.
Printing result to stdout. Use --output to specify output path.
13:00:01.879 [main] ERROR org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend - Error while running the command.
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:98) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:843) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:240) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1087) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1165) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28) [flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1165) [flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.

        at org.apache.flink.util.ExceptionUtils.rethrow(ExceptionUtils.java:321) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
------------------------------------------------------------
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(ExecutionEnvironment.java:1061) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.executeAsync(ContextEnvironment.java:132) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:70) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:942) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.collect(DataSet.java:417) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.print(DataSet.java:1748) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.examples.java.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:96) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
 The program finished with the following exception:

        at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(ExecutionEnvironment.java:1056) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.executeAsync(ContextEnvironment.java:132) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:70) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:942) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.collect(DataSet.java:417) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.print(DataSet.java:1748) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.examples.java.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:96) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$11(RestClusterClient.java:448) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:271) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils$Timeout.run(FutureUtils.java:1125) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.DirectExecutorService.execute(DirectExecutorService.java:217) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$orTimeout$12(FutureUtils.java:489) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils$Timeout.run(FutureUtils.java:1125) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.DirectExecutorService.execute(DirectExecutorService.java:217) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$orTimeout$12(FutureUtils.java:489) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:98)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:843)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:240)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1087)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1165)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1165)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
        at org.apache.flink.util.ExceptionUtils.rethrow(ExceptionUtils.java:321)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(ExecutionEnvironment.java:1061)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.executeAsync(ContextEnvironment.java:132)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:70)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:942)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.collect(DataSet.java:417)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.print(DataSet.java:1748)
        at org.apache.flink.examples.java.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:96)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(ExecutionEnvironment.java:1056)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$11(RestClusterClient.java:448)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:271)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils$Timeout.run(FutureUtils.java:1125)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.DirectExecutorService.execute(DirectExecutorService.java:217)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$orTimeout$12(FutureUtils.java:489)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        ... 9 more
```

Job submission to flink through Dockerfile